# Running multiple threads of a php script on server

Tags: php, multithreading

I am currently trying to use [fat controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/) to handle multiple threads of a php script on a unix server. The script command is as follows `php script.php arg1 thID` where `arg1` is an **arument** and `thID` is the **thread id**. I am trying to figure out how to append both an **argument** and the **thread id** to the command but I'm having no luck. Do you guys know how to do this, or a similar manager that can help me do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use screen instead?

```
screen -A -m -d -S some_name_for_screen php script.php arg1 arg2 arg3
```

to attach to your process use:

```
screen -x some_name_for_screen
```

to detach

```
press ctrl+a+d
```

to list processes type

```
screen -list
```

-A is for auto console size
-m -d means not to attach to created screen
-S name is for named screen

then there is a command

And i dont think it's called multithreading :)

Comment: I cant do that, we are talking about 500 processes or threads... cant do it all manualy.

Comment: So why dont you create a php (or better BASH) script to run php scripts?

for($I = 0; $I < 100; $I++)
{
 exec(sprintf('screen -A -m -d -S PhpServer_%d php script.php %d', $I, $I));
}

Comment: I am doing that currently, and not within screens, but there is a lot that can go wrong, so id rather have something more well developed and not just a fork behind it.

Comment: In my opinion spawning hundreds of processes is not good practise. Maybe tell us what is your exact problem to solve. Is it a kind of web based client application?

Comment: Yes, it has to request data from several sources, and i need it done as fast as possible, so hense i multythread.

Comment: Is it a http request?
Note that each process needs its own memory space which is not small for php. In sockets you can use select http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php to get information on which socket there is something waiting for you. You can set non-blocking to all operations to prevent waiting for that operation to finish. This is how web servers like nginx handles thousands of requests with single thread.

Comment: they are complicated requests with cookies and through proxies, so i am using curl.

Comment: Ok, so i guess you are creating a spambot :P
How about using built-in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: lol... I am already using fork :) trying to find something more... stable.

Comment: Note that fork is nearly an equivalent of runing another process. The most stable, controlable and powerful would be using sockets. The only problem is in proxy support. Are you using socks5?